# The orthogonalized plane waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

An orthogonal plane wave with wave number $k$ is written as

$$ OPW_k=e^{ ik\cdot r}-\sum_\alpha \psi_\alpha(r) \int \psi^*_\alpha (r'') e^{ik\cdot r''} d\tau'',$$

where index $\alpha$ and $k$ stands for core states and conduction band states.

In the above equation first term is plan wave term and in second term we use two wave functions $\psi_\alpha(r)$ and $\psi^*_\alpha (r'')$ for core states. My question is why do we use two wave functions and why do subtract second term from the first term ?

Comment: Just made some minor fixes to your formatting.

Comment: Where is this equation coming from (what context)? And what is $\tau''$? Do you mean $r''$?

Comment: I don't know. why do they use $ \tau^" $  i have got this problem while studying OPW method. Thank you @Michael Brown for your cooperation.

Comment: I guess the $d\tau''$ in the integral should be a $dr''$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\psi_\alpha(r) \int \psi^*_\alpha (r'') e^{ik\cdot r''} dr''
$$

is the component of $\Psi_\alpha(r)$ **not** orthogonal to $e^{ik\cdot r}$.

So one is subtracting all components not orthogonal to any existing (basis) function $\Psi_\alpha(r)$ from the (newly added) plane wave $e^{ik\cdot r}$, similar to [Gram Schmidt orthogonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) .